# Convert Json output in table

Tags: php, arrays, json, mashape

Below is the mashape api, here i want api output should be in table.

```
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"X-Mashape-Key: XXXXXXXXXX"               
)
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$res = file_get_contents('https://sphirelabs-indian-telecom-data-recharge-plans-v1.p.mashape.com/telecomdata/v1/get/index.php?circle=tn&opcode=idea&type=Topup', false, $context);
print_r(json_decode($res, true));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 10 [recharge_talktime] => 7.90 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea Talktime of Rs. 7.9 on a recharge of Rs. 10 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => TRUE ) [1] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 20 [recharge_talktime] => 15.80 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea Talktime of Rs. 15.8 on a recharge of Rs. 20 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => FALSE ) [2] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 25 [recharge_talktime] => 19.75 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea 2 Local Idea Night Minutes (11pm to 6am) | Tariff Validity (Days): 2 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => FALSE ) [3] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 30 [recharge_talktime] => 23.70 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea Talktime of Rs. 23.7 on a recharge of Rs. 30 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => FALSE ) [4] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 35 [recharge_talktime] => 35.00 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea 2 Local Idea Night Minutes (11pm to 6am) | Talktime Validity (Days): 5 | Tariff Validity (Days): 5 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => FALSE ) [5] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 36 [recharge_talktime] => 29.04 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea 2 Local Idea Night Minutes (11pm to 6am) | Tariff Validity (Days): 2 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => FALSE ) [6] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 50 [recharge_talktime] => 41.50 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea Talktime of Rs. 41.5 on a recharge of Rs. 50 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => TRUE ) [7] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 55 [recharge_talktime] => 55.00 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea 2 Local Idea Night Minutes (11pm to 6am) | Tariff Validity (Days): 2 [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => TRUE ) [8] => Array ( [recharge_amount] => 100 [recharge_talktime] => 100.00 [recharge_validity] => N.A [recharge_description] => Idea Full Talktime [recharge_type] => Topup [recharge_operator] => Idea [recharge_circle] => TamilNadu [recharge_isRecommended] => TRUE ) )
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show some effort. Add your current output and your expected output.

Comment: I have no idea, how to put above output in table. So it is clear that above is my current output and expected output will be simple html table.

Comment: Have you even tried it? Use google for 5 minutes and try something. You will be surprised how far you get.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring out whatever it is you need to do. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$res = file_get_contents('https://sphirelabs-indian-telecom-data-recharge-plans-v1.p.mashape.com/telecomdata/v1/get/index.php?circle=tn&opcode=idea&type=Topup', false, $context);
$data = json_decode($res, true);
if (count($data) > 0): ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><?= implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($data))); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <tr>
  <?php foreach ($row as $item): ?>
      <td><?= $item ?></td>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```